# How do I enable ssl for all controllers in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, ssl-certificate, openid

I have a MVC 5 app and I installed the ssl certificate and I'm now connecting with https, but in my code I had to set the '[requirehttps]' attribute on the homecontroller like so:

```
[RequireHttps]
public class HomeController : Controller
{}
```

Isn't there a way to set it for the whole application so I don't have to do this for each and every controller I have in the app?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in your `FiltersConfig`.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this  ?

Answer (score 4):

The `[RequireHttps]` attribute is inherited, so you could create a base controller, apply the attribute to that, and then derive all your controllers from that base.

```
[RequireHttps]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{}

public class FooController : BaseController
{}
```

Comment: that would be even more work then adding the attribute to each controller, I was looking for less work? Maybe some general attribute setting or something?

Comment: Not a lot of work.  A simple find-and-replace on "Controller : Controller", and replace with "Controller : BaseController", across the project in visual studio should do the trick.

Comment: ok well it would almost be the same amount of work as creating the attribute above each controller, nonetheless I was looking for a different solution. If there is one...